# Symfony 1.4 session not persistent

Tags: php, symfony-1.4

I have no idea what happened, it used to work. In my action:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute ('sname', 'Valueeee');
$this->redirect ('homepage');
```

and in my components:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('sname');
```

Its NULL! I know its not too much, but what can I do?

Comment: interestingly, I can see the sess_******* file, and its empty

Answer (score 0):

If you all want to cry and laugh at the same time: I overridden the "myUser::shutdown()" method, and nobody told to call its parent...